# How to enable gzip compression on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, gzip

On old Parse forums there are threads where they talk about gzip beeing enabled on parse but looks like they work only on html files.

How do I enable gzip compression for all other files in public directory like JavaScript, CSS and Images?